# Replacing image src, once image is loaded

Tags: jquery

I have this code which fades in multiple images only after they are loaded. It is triggered even when image is loaded from the cache.

```
$(".image-class").one("load", function() {
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Now, when the load completes, if the width of the image is less than 130, I want to load another image in it's place. Nothing is to be shown until the 2nd image is loaded.

```
$(imgID).one("load", function() {
    // check if image is too small
    if($(this).width() < 130 ){
        $(this).attr("src","larger_image.jpg");
    }else{
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    }
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

This does load a different photo if width < 130. But it never seems to trigger `load` for the 2nd image. The `fadeIn` never triggers for the 2nd image, so it's never shown.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) to register the handler, which will trigger the handler only once after which the handler is discarded

```js
var imgID = 'img';
$(imgID).on("load", function() {
  // check if image is too small
  if ($(this).width() < 130) {
    $(this).attr("src", "//placehold.it/150x64");
  } else {
    $(this).fadeIn("slow").off('load');
  }
}).hide().each(function() {
  if (this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="//placehold.it/64x64" />
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! Will changing one to on have any adverse effect on the code?

Comment: @Yeti we are removing the handler once it is used... so I guess no

Comment: ok cool. One last thing - if the 2nd image size is also less than 130 then all hell breaks loose. How can any further execution be stopped if 2nd image size is also less than 130?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hxpzjkwz/4 will not load from the cache, right? since it doesn't have  if (this.complete) $(this).load();. I'm not sure though.